# Left join on custom collection, to get product name by product ID

Tags: collection, join

There's a collection which contains product ids. I'd like to join it with the magento table that stores paroduct names, in order to add product name to collection.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("productquestions/questions")->getCollection();
$this->setCollection($collection);

$collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(I_NEED_HELP_IN_THIS_PART_OF_CODE);
```

The table that's used to get collection is "nbpq_product_questions" and the column that stores product id is "product_id".

I've seen some code examples about left join collection, but I can't make it work in this particular case. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of starting from your collection, we should start from the Magento's product collection.

```
<?php

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('your_table' => $this->getTable('productquestions/questions')),
        'e.entity_id = your_table.product_id'
    );
```

Before using this code, make sure that the `$this->getTable()` function is returning your table correctly. If not, that part needs to be modified based on your `config.xml` file's `<entity>` tag content.

Since Magento is saving the Product data in EAV table structure, it is not an easy task to write the correct `JOIN` query to get the Product name. To make it simple, Magento is proving the `addAttributeToSelect` method. That's why we are starting from the Product collection rather than starting from your collection.

Comment: But will the 'productquestions/questions' table data still be available, using this kind of join?

Comment: @ktsixit Yes, as you can see, we are joining your table. Hence those columns will also be available in the collection.

Comment: @ktsixit Please accept it as answer if it resolves your problem

Comment: I need some time to test it